# Extract all function from source file without evaluating it

Tags: r, parsing, metaprogramming, rlang

For my package I am looking for a method to identify all function assignments in a user supplied `R` script, **without** executing it.

So let's assume the following example script (`ex.R`):

#### `ex.R`

```r
## user supplied script
a <- function(x) 1
b1 = b2 <- function() {
   y <- 1
   2 -> j
   j
}
d <<- function(x) {
   k <- function(l) 1
   k(x)
}
(function(x) 2) -> e
(function() {
   y <- 1
   2 -> j
   j
}) -> f1 -> f2
(function() 1)()
g <- 4
5 -> h
i <- lapply(1:3, FUN = function(x) x + 1)
assign('j', function() 1)
k1 <- (function() {1}) -> k2
```

The function should return `c("a", "b1", "b2", "d", "e", "f1", "f2", "j", "k1", "k2")`

I came up with the following solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
code <- parse("ex.R")

get_identifier <- function(nm) {
   if (is.symbol(nm)) {
      deparse(nm)
   } else if (is.character(nm)) {
      nm
   } else {
      stop(paste0("unknown type", typeof(nm), "for `nm`"))
   }
}

get_fns <- function(expr) {
   assignment_ops <- c("<-", "=", "assign", "<<-")
   is_assign <- deparse(expr[[1L]]) %in% assignment_ops
   is_call <- is_assign && is.call(expr[[3L]])
   if (is_call) {
      next_call <- deparse(expr[[3L]][[1L]])
      if (next_call == "function") {
         get_identifier(expr[[2L]])
      } else if (next_call %in% c(assignment_ops, "(")) {
         c(get_identifier(expr[[2L]]), Recall(expr[[3L]]))
      } else {
         NULL
      }
   } else {
      NULL
   }
}

unlist(lapply(code, get_fns))
# [1] "a"  "b1" "b2" "d"  "e"  "f2" "f1" "j"  "k1" "k2"
```

Which is correct for at least this use case.

But adding just two other nasty edge cases will break the code:

```r
l1 <- (1 + (l2 <- function(x) 2 * x)(3))
(m <- function(x) x)
```

should return `c("l2", "m")`, but it does not. My recursion is somewhere at fault, but I cannot spot the problem. How would I fix the code?

---

### Update

The comment showed that I should explain a bit what I want to achieve eventually:

1. I want to develop a package which takes an "arbitrary" R script (`script.R` say) and transforms this script into a script which has a Command Line Interface (`script_ammended.R` say), that is which can be eventually called via `Rscript ammended_script.R [ARGS]`.
2. The idea is that user script contains some functions with some special comments and via those the CLI is auto-generated.
3. I know that there a couple of libraries, which enable a decent command line parsing already, but all of them require of course that the user spends some time on CLI programming.
4. My use case is somewhat different. I want a standalone script, which simply uses some functions to do what it is meant to do. If the user later wants to create a CL tool out of it, it should be as easy as pressing a button (assuming that the user add some minimal comments to the original functions).
5. The auto generated script will always add extra code, to log, to make sure that needed libraries are installed and so on.

A contrived example may look like this:

#### `script.R`

```r
greet <- function(msg, from = "me") {
   #! short: -g
   #! params: [., -f]
   #! description: greeting <msg> from user <me> is shown
   print(paste0("Message from <", from, ">: ", msg))
}

bye <- function() {
   #! short: -b
   greet("Good Bye", "system")
}

greet("Test")
```

This would be a typical user script, which can be quite conveniently used interactively. Now, my package should take this script and turn it into the following script:

#### `script_amended.R`

```r
library(optigrab)

greet <- function(msg, from = "me") {
   print(paste0("Message from <", from, ">: ", msg))
}

bye <- function() {
   greet("Good Bye", "system")
}

msg <- opt_get("g", default = NA_character_, 
               description = "greeting <msg> from user <me> is shown")
from <- opt_get("f", default = "me")
bye_flag <- opt_get("b", default = FALSE)


if (!is.na(msg)) {
   greet(msg, from)
   quit(status = 0)
} else if (bye_flag) {
   bye()
   quit(status = 0)
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply execute the script in a closed environment and return the name of objects of mode `function`? There are lots of other "nasty" edge cases that your code will miss. (off the top of my head: `list2env`, `eval`, `source`, `load`, `getfromNamespace`, `Rcpp::cppFunction`). To be a complete solution, you would need to write an R parser. Fortunately, you already have one - R itself. You should use it if you want to cover _all_ the bases.

Comment: Pretty sure there was a package that extracts all vars and makes a network plot, which could be useful, but can't remember the name.

Comment: It's probably better when your code can cover all cases, but I've never encountered at least 50% of these syntaxes, and the way `l1` is defined seems very convoluted. Out of curiosity, have you ever seen some code like this?

Comment: Maybe add regex tag?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, and I am fully aware that there are a myriad of possibilities how to define a function and I do not want to cover all of them (as I do not want to write a new R parser). I will add some background info to the post to explain what I am ultimately after.

Comment: what if the function was defined as `f <- function() x
# Note the specification of a "..." argument:
formals(f) <- al <- alist(x = , y = 2+3, ... = )
f`? Check the help page of `alist`. The best option is to is to follow what @AllanCameron stated. If at all the script contains some expensive computations, consider describing how you want the function to be defined and if possible, to let the user know that you require the functions in their own file

Comment: Made a mistake for the `l1` use case fixed it. Now `l2` is indeed a function.

Comment: Consider putting some bounty on the question. Inthat case someone might be excited to help you out

Comment: @bretauv addmitedly, some of the uses cases are rather contrived, but I do see code like this quite often in nature `if (any(x <- 1:4 %% 2 == 0)) [...]`. So an assignment within another call is not that uncommon. Also chained assignemnts are not uncommon. Mixed left/right assignments/equal signs are rather rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good sleep, I could reduce the (recursive) problem to 5 simple cases:

1. If the expression under investigation (`expr`) is not a call, we stop and return `NULL`.
2. If we hit a bracket, simply recurse into the expression and keep the current list of potential identifiers.
3. If we hit a `function`, we simply return the vector of potential identifiers collected so far.
4. If we hit an assignment operator, add the identifier to the list of potential identifiers and recurse into the RHS of the assignment.
5. In any other case, we loop through all elements of the call, but reset the list of potential identifiers to `NULL`.

```r
extract_function <- function(expr, identifiers = NULL) {
   .OP <- 1L
   .LHS <- 2L
   .RHS <- 3L
   .ASGNM <- c("<-", "<<-", "=", "assign")
   if (is.call(expr)) {
      op <- deparse(expr[[.OP]])
      if (op == "(") {
         ## bracket case: simply recurse into the call and keep identifiers
         res <- Recall(expr[[-.OP]], identifiers)
      } else if (op == "function") {
         ## function case: we can stop and return stored identifiers
         res <- identifiers
      } else if (op %in% .ASGNM) {
         ## assignment case: add LHS to potential list of identifiers
         res <- Recall(expr[[.RHS]], c(as.character(expr[[.LHS]]), identifiers))
      } else {
         ## else case: drop identifiers and recurse into function
         res <- lapply(expr, extract_function, identifiers = NULL) |>
            unlist()
      }
   } else {
      res <- NULL
   }
   res
}

unlist(lapply(parse("ex.r"), extract_function))
# [1] "a"  "b2" "b1" "d"  "e"  "f1" "f2" "j"  "k2" "k1" "l2" "m"
```

Answer (score 2):

Credits to Allan Cameron's comments to run the script, below a function to use exactly that approach.

```
functions_from_source <- function(source) {
  
  myEnv <- new.env()  
  
  source(source, local = myEnv)
  
  objects <- ls(envir = myEnv)
  
  funs <- sapply(objects, \(x){
    is.function(eval(parse(text = x), envir = myEnv))
  })
  
  objects[funs]
  
  rm(envir = myEnv)
  
}

functions_from_source("ex.R")

# [1] "a"  "b1" "b2" "e"  "f1" "f2" "j"  "k1" "k2" "m"
```

**ex.R** including m and l1 (note R does not interpret l2 as a function but as a value)

```
a <- function(x) 1
b1 = b2 <- function() {
  y <- 1
  2 -> j
  j
}
d <<- function(x) {
  k <- function(l) 1
  k(x)
}
(function(x) 2) -> e
(function() {
  y <- 1
  2 -> j
  j
}) -> f1 -> f2
(function() 1)()
g <- 4
5 -> h
i <- lapply(1:3, FUN = function(x) x + 1)
assign('j', function() 1)
k1 <- (function() {1}) -> k2

l1 <- (1 + (l2 <- (function(x) 2 * x)(3)))
(m <- function(x) x)
```

Comment: This evaluates the script.

Comment: @onyambu, yes it does I basically took the approach already suggested in the comments., will add those credits. I also think this is the way to go. It would detect `(m <- function(x) x)` as well, but we can also clearly see that `l1 <- (1 + (l2 <- (function(x) 2 * x)(3)))` is interpretted by R as a value and not a function despite's OP's expectations. Besides this to be far less complex, it is way error prone to know whether R considers something a function or not.

Comment: also you do not have to parse the objects in the environment as they have already been evaluated. ie use `names(which(unlist(eapply(myEnv,is.function))))` after the source

Comment: or even `names(Filter(is.function, mget(ls(myEnv), myEnv)))`

Comment: Well, it does execute the script, which I want to avoid (what if the script takes ages or has side effects). Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Tried reducing the function: Though might have some edge cases. Not sure.

```
get_fun <- function(x){
  dp <- deparse1(x[[1]])
  if( dp %in% c('<-', '=', '<<-'))  c(x[[2]], get_fun(x[[3]]))
  else if(dp == c('(')) get_fun(x[[2]])
  else if(dp == 'assign') as.list(x[-1])
  else if(dp == 'function') x
  else if(any(i<-grepl("<<?-",x))) c(NA, get_fun(x[[which(i)]]))
}

get_name <- function(y){
  x <- head(get_fun(y), -1)
  if (length(x) > 1 & any(i <- is.na(x))) x <- tail(x,-max(which(i)))
  as.character(x)
}

get_fns <- function(file){
  unlist(lapply(parse(file), get_name))
}

get_fns('ex.R')
 [1] "a"       "b1"      "b2"      "d"       "e"       "f2"     
 [7] "f1"      "j"       "k1"      "k2"      "l2"      "m"
```

The usage of `get_fun` is quite simple. eg:

suppose we have:

```
 z <- alist(   l1 <- (1 + (l2 <- function(x) 2 * x)(3)),
               (s = (m <- function(x) x))->k, 
              d <- (((function(x)x+2))),
              i <- lapply(1:3, FUN = function(x) x + 1),
              j <- lapply(1:3, FUN <- function(x) x + 1))
```

Notice that we have `l2, m, d, FUN`. The `FUN` is from `j` and not `i` since we used `<-` meaning we assigned the function and not merely a parameter:

From `l1` we get:

```
get_fun(z[[1]])
[[1]]
l1

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] NA

[[4]]
l2

[[5]]
function(x) 2 * x
```

We only pick everything after all the `NAs`:

```
get_fun(z[[2]])
[[1]]
k

[[2]]
s

[[3]]
m

[[4]]
function(x) x

get_fun(z[[3]])
[[1]]
d

[[2]]
function(x) x + 2

get_fun(z[[4]])
[[1]]
i
```

For `z[[4]]` although there is a name, there is no function associated with the name. Thus not a valid function

```
get_fun(z[[5]])
[[1]]
j

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
FUN

[[4]]
function(x) x + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Does work and is indeed WAY easier (a small bug though for the `assign` case if you supply further arguments (so instead of `[-1]` we should use `[2:3]`). After a good sleep, I could even come up with a very simple recursive function. which I will post. +1

Comment: @thothal could you give an example of `assign` tht does not work?

Comment: `assign("x", function() 1, immediate = TRUE)`